# Json split print_r to foreach

Tags: php, foreach, json

I have the following code

```
$List2 = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://___URL____&format=json"),true);
```

the following works perfectly

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($List2);echo '</pre>';
```

and produces e.g.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [uid] => 123456
        [name] => John Williams
        [pic_square] => http://nc4/565228_799523_q.jpg
        [birthday_date] => 07/31/1987
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [uid] => 123789
        [name] => Jane Thompson
        [pic_square] => http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/785505233_1702140670_q.jpg
        [birthday_date] => 07/31/1983
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [uid] => 456789
        [name] => John Gaffney
        [pic_square] => http://profet/hprofile-ak-snc4/3717297628_q.jpg
        [birthday_date] => 07/31/1965
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [uid] => 987654
        [name] => Johnny Illand
        [pic_square] => http://c4/41766_14329_q.jpg
        [birthday_date] => 07/31/1958
    )
```

I want to run a foreach to print the result somewhat neater obviously, so i'm trying the following:

```
$data = $List2['data'] ;

foreach ($data as $nr => $friends){

echo $friends[name].' - ';

}
```

But I get

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

I'm stumped and it's probably something easy!

Comment: You should simply use `$List2` instead of `$data` (which additionally would be `null`). You are printing one thing, and then iterating over another. Is the result surprising?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
foreach ($List2 as $element)
    echo $element[name].' - ';
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example the 'data' key does not exists

`$data = $List2;`